# What is the proper way of utilizing browser cache without using expiration?

Tags: html, browser-cache

I don't want to use expiration, because I don't know how often my resources (css, js, etc) will change. A case might be where I push something to production, but soon find out I have some bugs in the resources. So I fixed the bugs, then push the updated resources into production, but they're in production before the expiration date. How do I force the browser to use the updated resources instead of cache?

I don't want to use fingerprinting (dynamic resource filename based of version type), because those resources are located in an svn directory. Meaning, I would have to manually modify the filename using svn every time I change the code version (maybe there's somewhat to automate this?).

Utilizing `http-equiv="last-modified"` would be the preferred option, but that doesn't seem to work properly.

Also maybe I just don't know how all this works. Please enlighten me. Many thanks in advance.

-- Tri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to have all references to those resources to append a version number to the query string or elsewhere in the URL, for example "styles/site.css?version=1.0".  That way, since the URL will change during your next release, your browser will see it as a different URL and will not use the file from cache.

If you ever change to using a CDN, deploying all resources to version numbered folders can achieve the same goal.

Comment: Well, isn't that the same as fingerprinting?

Comment: No.  You wouldn't have to rename the files; you can just reference it with a query string addition.

Comment: oooh ooh I get it now. That's pretty cool. Thanks. Btw, what's a CDN?

Comment: Content distribution network.  Akamai is an example of a CDN provider.